# SQL query to fetch distinct records

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone help me out with this sql query on postgres which I have to write but I just can't come up with, I have tried my best to simplify the problem from 1 million records and more constraints to this, I know this looks easy, but I am still unable to resolve this somehow  :-

Table_name = t

Column_1_name = id

Column_2_name = st

Column_1_elements = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]

Column_2_elements = [a,b,c,d,a,c,d,b,d]

Now I want to print to those distinct ids from id where they do not have their corresponding  st equals to 'b' or 'a'.

For example, for the above example, the ouput should be [2,3] as 2 does not have corresponding 'b' and 3 does not have 'a'. [even though 3 does not have c also, but we are not concerned about 'c']. id=1 is not returned in solution as it has a relation with both 'a' and 'b'.

Let me know if you need more clarity.
Thanks in advance for helping.

edit1:- The number of elements for id = 1,2,3 could be anything. I just want those ids where there corresponding st does not "contain" 'a' or 'b'.
if there is an id=4 which has just one st which is 'r', and there is an id=5 which contains 'a','b','c','d','e','f','k','z'.
Then we want id=4 in the output as well as it does not contain 'a' or 'b'..

Comment: `select distinct on(id) id from st where st not in ('a', 'b')`.

Comment: Your problem description needs work, '...  distinct ids from id where they do not have their corresponding st equals to 'b' or 'a'' is at odds with your edit1 example.  You are not looking for a one to one between `id` and `str`, but the case where the set of values associated with a given `id` does not contain both 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to correct the syntax a little bit based on you SQL engine but this one is a working solution in Google BigQuery -

```
with temp as (
    select 1 as id, 'a' as st union all
    select 1 as id, 'b' as st union all
    select 1 as id, 'c' as st union all
    select 1 as id, 'd' as st union all
    select 2 as id, 'a' as st union all
    select 2 as id, 'c' as st union all
    select 2 as id, 'd' as st union all
    select 3 as id, 'b' as st union all
    select 3 as id, 'd' as st union all
    select 4 as id, 'e' as st union all 
    select 5 as id, 'g' as st union all 
    select 5 as id, 'h' as st 

)

-- add 2 columns for is_a and is_b flags
, temp2 as (
select *
, case when st = 'a' then 1 else 0 end is_a 
,case when st = 'b' then 1 else 0 end  as is_b
from temp
)

-- IDs that have both the flags as 1 should be filtered out (like ID = 1)
select id
from temp2
group by 1
having max(is_a) + max(is_b) < 2
```

This solution takes care of the problem you mentioned with ID 4 . Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This solution will work for this, but I need a more generic solution. I have edited the question and added an edge case:-

The number of elements for id = 1,2,3 could be anything. I just want those ids where there corresponding st does not "contain" 'a' or 'b'. if there is an id=4 which has just one st which is 'r', and there is an id=5 which contains 'a','b','c','d','e','f','k','z'. Then we want id=4 in the output as well as it does not contain 'a' or 'b' along with id=2 and id=3..

Comment: I have updated my answer with the new cases. Now as you see, it can handle case for id 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
create table t (id integer, st varchar);

insert into t values (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'r');

insert into t values (5, 'a'), (5, 'b'), (5, 'c'), (5, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (5, 'f'), (5, 'k'), (5, 'z');

select id, array['a', 'b'] <@ array_agg(st)::text[] as tf from t group by id;

id | tf 
----+----
  3 | f
  5 | t
  4 | f
  2 | f
  1 | t


select * from (select id, array['a', 'b'] <@ array_agg(st)::text[] as tf from t group by id) as agg where agg.tf = 'f';

id | tf 
----+----
  3 | f
  4 | f
  2 | f
```

In the first select query the `array_agg(st)` aggregates all the `st` values for an `id` via the `group by id`. `array['a', 'b'] <@ array_agg(st)::text[]` then asks if the `a` and `b` are both in the `array_agg`.

The query is then turned into a sub-query where the outer query selects those rows that where `'f'`(false), in other words did not have both `a` and `b` in the aggregated `id` values.